# Fluentbit (как отключить обёртку JSONа в JSON)?

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka

В nginx пишутся логи в JSON формате далее Fluentbit берёт эти логи и отправляет в Kafka, смотрю что прилетает в Kafka и вижу что Fluentbit мой JSON (из nginx) обернул ещё раз в свой JSON. Получился JSON в JSONе

Как отключить повторную обёртку в JSON?

vi nginx.conf

```
log_format main_json escape=json '{'
                '"@timestamp":$msec,'
                '"appName":"pirate",'
                '"localTime":"$time_iso8601",'
                '"level":"INFO",'
                '"text":"client=$remote_addr method=$request_method request=$request request_length=$request_length time_local=$time_local status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent referer=$http_referer remote_user=$remote_user user_agent=$http_user_agent upstream_addr=$upstream_addr upstream_status=$upstream_status request_time=$request_time upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time",'
                '"eventId":"33637347-6246-7641-3185-75346984632",'
                '"appType":"NGINX",'
                '"levelInt":1,'
                '"loggerName":"io.tracing.internal.reporters.LoggingReporter",'
                '"threadName":"http-nio-8080-exec-3",'
                '"callerClass":"io.tracing.internal.reporters.LoggingReporter",'
                '"callerMethod":"report",'
                '"callerLine":"1",'
                '"envType":"fluentd",'
                '"namespace":"kx-dc",'
                '"podName":"mf-nginxhost",'
                '"es_index_name_suffix":"kx-dc.nginx",'
                '"tslgClientVersion":"0.0.1",'
                '"tec":{"nodeName":"mf-nginxhost.test.datacenter.ru",'
                '"podIp":"10.64.122.125"}'
        '}';
```

vi fluent-bit.conf

```
# Fluentbit Config
[SERVICE]
    Flush           1
#   Parsers_File    parsers.conf
 
[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 nginxaccess.*
    Path                /app/nginx/logs/*.log
    LineFormat          json
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    1
 
[OUTPUT]
    Name Kafka
    Match *
    Topics tslg-app-logs
    Timestamp_Key time
    Brokers testhost-kafka.test.datacenter.ru:9092
    rdkafka.request.required.acks 1
    rdkafka.log.connection.close false
    rdkafka.compression.codec snappy
    rdkafka.security.protocol ssl
    rdkafka.ssl.ca.location /opt/fluentbit/etc/fluent-bit/newcert2/ca-kafka-cert.pem
    rdkafka.ssl.certificate.location /opt/fluentbit/etc/fluent-bit/newcert2/client-kafka-cert.pem
    rdkafka.ssl.key.location /opt/fluentbit/etc/fluent-bit/newcert2/client-kafka-cert-key.pem
```

в кафку залетает JSONы такого формата:

```
    {
      "time": 1671104247.099066,
      "log": "{\"@timestamp\":1671104247.098,\"appName\":\"pirate\",\"localTime\":\"2022-12-15T14:37:27+03:00\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"text\":\"client\u003d10.186.26.250 method\u003dGET request\u003dGET /api/v1/applic_list/representative/credentials HTTP/2.0 request_length\u003d58 time_local\u003d15/Dec/2022:14:37:27 +0300 status\u003d200 bytes_sent\u003d961 body_bytes_sent\u003d397 referer\u003dhttps://mf-nginxhost.test.datacenter.ru/cash/cash-app/new remote_user\u003d user_agent\u003dMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36 upstream_addr\u003d10.223.18.104:8443 upstream_status\u003d200 request_time\u003d0.198 upstream_response_time\u003d0.199 upstream_connect_time\u003d0.010 upstream_header_time\u003d0.199\",\"eventId\":\"33637347-6246-7641-3185-75346984632\",\"appType\":\"NGINX\",\"levelInt\":1,\"loggerName\":\"io.tracing.internal.reporters.LoggingReporter\",\"threadName\":\"http-nio-8080-exec-3\",\"callerClass\":\"io.tracing.internal.reporters.LoggingReporter\",\"callerMethod\":\"report\",\"callerLine\":\"1\",\"envType\":\"fluentd\",\"namespace\":\"kx-dc\",\"podName\":\"mf-nginxhost\",\"es_index_name_suffix\":\"kx-dc.nginx\",\"tslgClientVersion\":\"0.0.1\",\"tec\":{\"nodeName\":\"mf-nginxhost.test.datacenter.ru\",\"podIp\":\"10.64.122.125\"}}"
    }
```